# "Access Denied" error using segue package in R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, segue, elastic-map-reduce

I suspect this is a very basic fix but I don't know what it is.

```
setCredentials(awsAccessKeyText = 'myaccesskey',
               awsSecretKeyText =  'mysecretkey')

myCluster <- createCluster(numInstances = 2)

Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: [RequestID], AWS Error Code: `AccessDenied, AWS Error Message: Access Denied, S3 Extended Request ID: [Longstringofrandomness]=`
```

What do I need to do to create the cluster successfully?
My access keys are generated for a user name that's the same as my computer user name. I'm new to the AWS system and haven't actually used it, but I do have an account.

On the package [code.google.com site](https://code.google.com/p/segue/) the only 'tip' is "To use Segue, you will need to have an Amazon Web Services account AND you will have to have the Elastic Map Reduce service activated. To see if you have the EMR service on, just follow this link."  I have followed the link and I do have the services activated... so what am I missing?

```
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, in case anyone else gets stuck at the same place.

After creating a new user in the IAM Management Console on AWS, that user must be given permission to do things. Under the "Permissions" tab, click the "Attach User Policy" button and then give that user permission to do whatever is prudent within your organization (in my case, the user was me, and the account is mine, so I gave myself admin permissions).

Then run

```
 myCluster <- createCluster(numInstances = 2)
```

which works for me!

Comment: This works for that step, however, the package fails to create working instances at this point. I e-mailed the package author and he said it's been about a year since he worked with segue and there may be "something wrong in the boot scripts". I suggest finding another way to work with AWS.